# python - importing plyfile

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I have seen the previous answers on this issue. None of which is helpful enough. I have tried to install `plyfile` with `pip3`. It says: 

`Requirement already satisfied: plyfile in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8 in ./.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages (from plyfile)`

Still, when I'm importing `plyfile` in Spyder, it shows the error: `No module named 'plyfile'`

Please help!

Comment: Does Splyder use python3 as well? Try `pip install plyfile`, see if that changes anything.

Comment: Yep, 3.6. And I don't have pip installed. I have pip3.
Is pip going to change anything?
Will notify.

Comment: UPDATE: I just saw that pip3 is used for python 3.x. There is no point in using pip, is there?

Answer (score 1):

That is due to plyfile installing to the built in python, not spyder. If you run python then import plyfile I bet it would work.

Please try `conda install plyfile` and if that doesnt work try

```
sudo su
pip install plyfile
```

Comment: Try 1: `PackageNotFoundError: Packages missing in current channels:
            
  - plyfile
`

Comment: Try 2:
`pip3 install plyfile

Requirement already satisfied: plyfile in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from plyfile)
`

Comment: What about `where python` and `where spyder`

Comment: that is strange, Package doesn't exist in anaconda resource,
conda command didn't work for me but when I used pip in terminal and update index in anaconda panel, the package is shown as installed 
pip install plyfile
my case was : OSX, python 3.6